# VSCode Does Not Recognize Git Folders not in Root

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is it possible for VSCode to recognize git repositories that are not at the root folder? For example, I have a folder structure like this:

`\Root
  <no git>
  \Folder1
    <git repo>
  \Folder2
    <git repo>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the December update we support git in a parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be at the root level and you can only connect to one repository at a time. You can use submodules in git to add another repository as a link to yours however and it can be in any sub directory.

Comment: Good to know. I can always drop to the command line which is what I usually do. I can also just open another VSCode instance in that folder if I want to take advantage of VSCode's git interface.

Comment: yes, i wouldn't use git submodules as they are pain to synchronize and manage, two instances of VSCode is probably a way to go

Comment: There's a good possibility that this could be added soon - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Roadmap#theme-highly-demanded-features, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/396